# Firebase authentication tracking table?

Tags: javascript, firebase, security, firebase-authentication

Does firebase track successful and non successful authentication attempts and can we render this data in an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase for reporting such data back to your app. If you want to report on log-in attempts, you'll have to build it yourself.

If you suspect abuse, be aware that Firebase has quite some experience with detecting and preventing abuse. If you have a concrete case where you suspect abuse, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Sounds good.  I thought perhaps something like https://myaccount.google.com/security might have been baked in such that each app could pull the data up.  I'm sure Google's security expertise has been put to good use here, but it's still nice for users to be able to monitor their accounts and a secondary precaution and in the event of a suspected breach.